# Huge initialization list, how to fix "fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, heap-memory

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ file that does:

```
static const unsigned char content[] = 
        {
              // 29MB of data written as "0x1E, 0x83, 0x3E, 0x86, 0xC8, 0x80, ...". 10 values per line
        };
```

The file to compile has almost 3M lines and is ~200Mo

This is an output from a ressources management system, trying to embed in my binary a 29Mo ressource file (let's assume it's a video file) for later use at runtime.

When I compile, VS2015 reports:

> fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space

Is there any alternative to that (use something else than a static const unsigned char)? Make the file have less lines but more characters per line? ...

Note: I tried /Zm1000 option without success.

Comment: I assume by Mo you mean MB? Why does that have to be in the sourcecode?

Comment: What does _29Mo_ mean? Please fix your post.

Comment: Is this static variable global or inside function?

Comment: This is bordering on an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes MB (Mo is in French). I need the file to be embedded in the binary to make it easier to deploy the binary on any machine. Also the user must not be allowed to modify the file used at runtime...so embedding it in the binary makes it being kind of "read-only".

Comment: You could try to embed the binary file as a resource. Start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632583.aspx

Comment: @bartop: Inside a constructor actually

Comment: @jpo38 The resource type `RT_RCDATA` is probably what you would be aiming to use.  Let the resource compiler (`rc.exe`) handle it at build time, not the C++ compiler.  The C++ code would then just need to read that resource into a dynamically allocated buffer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Unfortunately, this code is also compiled using QtCreator for Android (even if it will likely not run here with so many memory being used). So using rc is not an option for me...

Comment: The 64-bit compiler might be able to tackle it.  Change the VC++ Directories > Executable Directories setting to pick either $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x86), x64_x64 or x64_ARM, depending on the desired platform target.  Can't be much fun watching that grass grow, you are almost certainly going to change that utility to write a binary file.

Comment: @jpo38 I have not used Qt, but does [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) help (see *Compiled-In Resources*)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Qrc's generated C++ file also ends up with "compiler is out of heap space" error....

Comment: Switching to VS2017 might help (although I don't think it will).

Comment: Another option would be to append the binary data to the end of the .exe file and extract the data from the .exe file during runtime, but not sure if you can do this on Android.

Comment: @HansPassant: I had $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64). Replacing it by $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64_x64) fixed the issue! Thanks, you may want to post this as a real answer. Any idea how this option can be changed from CMake (My VS solution is generated from CMake).

Comment: I have no idea.  Be sure to include it in your own answer once you figure it out.

Comment: @HansPassant: My original question did not mention CMake, so I will accept your answer even if it does not tell how to do this within CMake generator.

Comment: Here's another SO question on embedding binary data into an object file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997569/commandline-tool-for-embedding-binary-file-into-obj-file

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060) on the subject:

> Eliminate unnecessary global variables, for example, by allocating
>   memory dynamically instead of declaring a large array.

and

> Split the current file into smaller files.

Both of which you should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, and I came upon the same issue trying to embed a large resource (24MB in my case) in a CPP file in the same way, when building for a Windows 32 bit target using Visual Studio 2017 using CMake. The default toolset when specifying `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` is actually the x86 host binary, which does fail with the Error C1060. However using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -T "host=x64"`, it uses the x64 host binary to build (still for the 32 bit x86 target) which completes successfully.