# Compliler out of heap size for large array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory, allocation

So I have a double array of 15,000,000 elements that during runtime, random subsets of 2000 elements from the array need to be extracted for processing.

I've tried initialising the array using the following:

```
static const double myArray[15000000] = {-2.1232, -6.4243, 23.432, ...};
```

However during runtime I get the error "C1060 compiler is out of heap space". In Visual Studio 2019, I've went into the project properties -> linker -> System and modified the Heap Reserve Size to "8000000000" which I assumed would be large enough and I have 16GB on my machine, but I still return the same error. I've also tried using the x64 compiler but to no avail.

I've also tried writing the array to a csv, and then binary file and reading from that instead during runtime. However, the read process takes far too long, as I'm required to read from it, ideally, several times a second.

I'm relatively new to C++, but especially new when it comes to memory allocation. What would you suggest as a solution?

Comment: why not load the array from a file?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you hard-coding a staggering number of values like this? Typically this is read from a file into a `std::vector` at run-time. The cost should be inconsequential.

Comment: That sounds like the compiler ran out of memory while trying to compile the application. Likely has something to do with the gigantic array.

Comment: Why do you need to read from a file several times per second? Just load it once, at startup. Reading the data from an external file shouldn't take longer than it takes to load it from the executable.

Comment: @seleciii44 I've tried that but the read process takes too long and the array still needs to be initialized.

Comment: @molbdnilo Wouldn't the array still require initialization in order to read the values into? I guess the crux of the problem is how do I store this array in memory even if I'm reading it from a file?

Comment: Use a pointer instead of an array. Allocate the array dynamically. Load a binary file into it.

Comment: arrays guaranty consequence memory layout, it can be that you dont have enough at your heap

Answer (score 2):

If you have your 15M doubles in binary format, you can [embed that into your binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740164/how-to-embed-link-binary-data-into-a-windows-module) and reference it. The run-time cost is just a bit more disk IO when first loading your binary, but that should be much faster than parsing a CSV.

Answer (score -2):

the problem may be that you have enough memory but it not a consequence.
so my suggestion is to use std::list

Comment: An `std::list` of doubles on a 64-bit platform takes up at least three times the size of an array or vector. The linked list is the most overrated data structure and is very rarely a good choice.

Comment: yes but it can use fragmented memory so it can use more heap space

Comment: It is also horribly, horribly slow. And the issue for the poster is not heap fragmentation at runtime, it's that the compiler runs out of memory.

Comment: you right about the run time, but he also said that he increase the amount of memory and the error continue. and also sizeof(double) and sizeof(double*) are both 8 so id doesn't reduce the size of the list to change it to pointers

Comment: He increased *the compiler's* heap size - not the size of his own proram - and the difference between `sizeof(double[15000000])` (which is 120000000) and `sizeof(double*)` (which is 4 or 8) is huge.

Comment: so I don't understand your suggestion, he needs the data do be accessible in run time at relative fast and need 2000 values from that array every process, so how double* instead of double[15000000] help him?

Comment: It helps because a) the compiler does not need to handle all that memory during compilation and linking, so the program will compile, and b) accessing a dynamically allocated array is as fast as accessing a static one.

Comment: so you say to do this?  double* arr = new Double[15000000]?